# ¿como unir dos tabla en otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Mi problema es que tengo dos tabla **entrada** y **salida** tiene relación con otra tabla **inventario**, quiero que muestre los producto de las entrada en mi tabla inventario y salida en mi tabla inventario este es mi consulta

```
select idinventario,i.identrada,(select nombre from entrada 
where identrada=i.identrada)as nombre,
i.idsalida, (select nombre from salida where idsalida=i.idsalida)as nombre1,
i.idusuario,(select login from usuario where idpersona=i.idusuario)as 
usuarios,   fecha_inventario,fecha_ingreso,fecha_salida,observacion from
inventario i inner join entrada e on i.identrada=e.identrada,inner join 
salida s on i.idsalida=s.idsalida;
```

Comment: Hola Deberias poner la estructura de las tablas, para dar una respuesta mas acertada

Comment: los subselects que estás utilizando son inecesarios, en ves de hacer esto :

(select nombre from salida where idsalida=i.idsalida)

haz

s.nombre as nombre1

... no comprendo muy bien que es lo que quieres lograr, pero puedo darme cuenta de que estás comenzando con sql, si puedieras compartirnos la estructura de las tablas y mas información de lo que quieres lograr te puedo ayudar a hacer un buen query que no haga llorar al niño jesús, no temas, todos lo hemos echo llorar cuando comenzamos.

Comment: para ver la estructura: `describe entrada;describe salida; describe usuario;`

Comment: Mi tabla de inventario tiene: idinventario, identrada, idsalida, idusuario, fecha_inventario, fecha_ingreso, fecha_salida, observacion;   pero la informacion de identrada y idsalida quiero que se muestre la informacion de ellas por separado, ya que esa tabla tiene informacion y quiero que aparsca alli....

Comment: en las tabla identrada, idsalida, lleva(codigo,nombre, tipo, cantidad y fecha) y en usuario el nombre quien abrio el sistema, esa informacion quiero que aparesca en mi formulario de inventario, de ante mano gracias por ayudarme, estoy que lloro

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que necesitas hacer es hacer una estructura que tengan las mismas columnas en las dos tablas, por ejemplo:

- id (id de salida o entrada según la tabla de origen)
- nombre
- fecha (fecha salida si esta en la tabla salida o entrada si esta en la otra)
- observaciones
- usuario
- tipo (esta es importante, hay que poner un texto fijo 'entrada' o 'salida' en el select indicado)

Luego solo hay que hacer las dos consultas respetando esta estructura y usar la función UNION

Acá está el manual: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

te dejo un mini ejemplo:

```
select idsalida as id, fecha_salida as fecha, observacion, 'salida' as tipo from salidas
UNION
select identrada as id, fecha_entrada as fecha, observacion, 'entrada' as tipo from entrada
```

Espero te sirva.